# Log_probabilities returned by tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am training a LSTM-CTC speech recognition system with using beam search decoding in the following configuration:

```
decoded, log_prob =
tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(
inputs,
sequence_length,
beam_width=100,
top_paths=3,
merge_repeated=True
)
```

The output of `log_probabilities` for a batch by the above decoder are like:

```
[[ 14.73168373, 14.45586109, 14.35735512],

[ 20.45407486, 20.44991684, 20.41798401],

[ 14.9961853 , 14.925807 , 14.88066769],
...,

[ 18.89863396, 18.85992241, 18.85712433],

[ 3.93567419, 3.92791557, 3.89198923],

[ 14.56258488, 14.55923843, 14.51092243]],
```

So how do these scores represent log probabilities and if I want to compare confidence for top paths among examples then what will be the normalisation factor?